# What are the differences between firstChild and [0]?

Tags: javascript

Do they serve the same purpose? If so, is `firstChild` better than `[0]`?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
// versus
document.getElementsByTagName('div').firstChild
```

Could it possibly be that `[0]` is more consuming?

Comment: A `NodeList`/`HTMLCollections` doesn't have a `firstChild`? Only single elements have.

Comment: From `+4` to `-3` in under a minute.. crazy old SO :D

Comment: @Zenith That hurts :D

Comment: @Bergi Your answer is helpful! I got it wrong, I saw it with some `getElementById` in my code and I naively thought it would return the "first child" of the `NodeList` as `[0]` does.

Comment: @JeromeJ Don't take it personally :) I think the initial upvotes cancelled most of the rep loss anyway. I'm guessing the downvotes were due to the point mentioned by Bergi above.

Comment: @Zenith I know I shouldn't care but it does affect me a bit still. My question wasn't "that" misleading, was it? I asked what were their differences as I didn't see any. I, generously invite Bergi to post his comment as an answer. (kalley's answer bugs me somehow! :/)

Comment: @JeromeJ I understand, 8 is a little excessive (especially considering I saw four upvotes when I arrived, so four other people who obviously didn't know either). Best to forget and don't let it knock your confidence!

Comment: @Zenith Nice point of view, thanks! I'll end here, SO starts complaining about extended discussion. Have a good day!

Answer (score 8):

`document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]` gets you the first div in that NodeList.

`document.getElementsByTagName('div').firstChild` is undefined because a NodeList does not have that property.